# How to find a string in a column that contains a lengthy "word" or set of characters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am looking for an unusually long word or grouping of characters in a specific column of data that contains notes written by users. For example, if something like this -

`I am looking for an unusuallylongwordorgroupingofcharactersina specific column`

- exists, I need to find it so I can add spaces if necessary.  My question is:  How do I find a word or set of characters that exceeds a certain number of characters?

The problem is that somewhere in this data, an unusually long word or grouping of characters is being parsed and causing an `OutOfMemoryException`, so I need to find the source and fix it.

Comment: It seems higly unlikely to me that a varchar field from a database row can throw an `OutOfMemoryException`. What is the length of the entire field?

Comment: The exception is in regards to a program that is pulling the data and doing something with it.  It's looping through and splitting on spaces. If it doesn't find spaces, it keeps looping.  Unfortunately, this is not something I am in a position to correct, so I need to fix the data instead.

Comment: it wouldn't give you exactly what you are looking for, but maybe a threshold of `len(REPLACE(Column,' ',''))/len(Column)` would give you the highest letter to space ratio to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex in C# if the raw string fits in memory: `\w{15,}` gives you words at least 15 characters in length. There are many ways to tweak this (lookahead, lookbehind, more specific character classes, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a C# stored procedure that can be run against the column in question.
It would split the column into  an array of strings containing a word  Then you can easily find the largest word in the column.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zxsa8hkf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

for details on how to, write install and debug a C# stored procedure in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers given, I created a program that pulls the data and tosses each word into a list.  It then pulls words of a given length (in my case, I did greater than 20 characters) and found the bad "word".  Now I can fix the data.

I appreciate all your help, guys.